# How to make a proper mute command which mutes when unmuted and unmutes when muted

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name='Muted')
    if member.has_roles(role):
        await ctx.send(f'{member.nick} has been unmuted!')
        await member.remove_roles(role)
    else:
        await ctx.send(f'{member.nick} has been muted!')
        await member.add_roles(role)
```

So I tried this piece of code here. I thought it would work since I don't see a mistake here.
But when I tried it, bot gave me this error.`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'has_roles'` I kinda looked up for it in the net but I couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [the documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.roles), I would suggest:

```
if role in member.roles:
```